# Sublime Text 2 console input

Tags: python, ruby, sublimetext2

I use Sublime Text 2 but it won't let me enter any value when my code asks for user input. (In other words: `input()` in Python and `gets` in Ruby fail to correctly prompt me for input).

Python throws an `EOFError` error (what you get when user doesn't enter anything).

Simply USER INPUT isn't working in Sublime Text 2 for me.

EDIT: FOR EXAMPLE

```
try:
    text = input('Enter something: ')
    print text
except EOFError:
    print('\nEOFError')

=> Enter something: #cannot enter anything to var "text"
=> EOFError
=> [Finished]
```

Comment: More better option for you is run the code on IDLE you can also code on idle

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Sublime text doesn't support that. But you can get around it (at least in python) by using [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), I use this for everything, it works pretty great. Its a little cooky though, as the tab is still editable like a normal sublime tab (which is good and bad)...

It also allows you to run the interpreter in multiple tabs, its basically awesome.

To install it you need `package control` this lets you easily install plugins. To get it go [here](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation), and follow the instructions. Once thats done:

- in Sublime press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (linux command in `ST` for 'goto anything').
- Type in 'install',
- click on 'sublime package control: install package'.
- Then select `SublimeREPL`. It will install it automatically.
- To use it go to `Tools>sublimerepl>python` from the menus.

To make the default build system SublimeREPL, you can follow these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732006/how-to-run-python-code-on-sublimerepl/23722631#23722631).

Comment: @pnemi - updated with instructions. you'll like package control, it gives you access to a heap of handy plugins.

Comment: How to make it looking like this - http://wuub.net/sublimerepl/debian2.png ? And how to bind some keys to it?

Comment: @pnemi - once you've installed it, goto `view>layout>rows:2`, this splits the screen. Then goto ` Tools>sublimerepl>python>python` this opens the new interpreter window, which you can then drag to the bottom view.

Comment: That probably doesn't suit me :-/
Is there any other great editor like ST2 which skips this hassle and these problems? Supporting HTML/RUBY/PYTHON etc?

Comment: @pnemi - I guess its quite a personal taste thing. I've used a bunch of other editors, but I had issues with all of them. Pycharm is quite contemporary, and had quite a good feel, but i don't know if it does ruby... Or you could use a more basic editor and shell combo.. I suggest sticking with ST2, its worth it! Good luck regardless ;)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P allowed me to access Package Control on my Win7 box.

Comment: Use TextWrangler. It opens up a terminal window, and allows you to debug. People have been coercing me to use sublime, and I do like editing multiple lines at once, but lacking an easy ability to run scripts from sublime makes it substandard.

Comment: But it's not working on pressing `ctrl+B`, I had to go the the tools>>options , Python - run current file. How to make it run automatically?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing @user . If there is a way to hook this up automatically

Comment: Mathias711 @fraxel Is there a way/shortcut to run it quickly as asked by user?

Comment: To make Ctrl+B work with this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732006/how-to-run-python-code-on-sublimerepl/23722631#23722631.

Answer (score 12):

Since, **Sublime** not directly support for input console. So, it is easy to get input in Sublime with following extra steps:

1. Make sure that you have install Package control in Sublime.

   - If you have no install Package control then, go to [here](https://packagecontrol.io/) then, click **install Now** button (top right)    copy those code and paste it in your **Console** (make sure you have tick the **Show Console** option) and Press Enter.   (after that restart sublime)
2. Go to ->Command Palette(**Cltr + Shift + p**) click "**Package Control: Install Package**"
3. Search : "**SublimeRepl**" and wait for Installing.
4. Once, it is Installed, ,**Restart Sublime**

   - Go to Tools you will see ""**SublimeRepl**" option at the bottom (which indicates that it is successfully installed in your sublime)
5. To run python scripts: Go to **Tools->SublimeRepl->Python->*Python-RUNcurrentfile*** option and your code is run in new Repl Tab.

Note: **This works fine for sublimeText3 (windows )**

Comment: Thanks. Is there a shortcut key to run current file ?

Comment: To make Ctrl+B work with this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732006/how-to-run-python-code-on-sublimerepl/23722631#23722631.