# How to Run Python Code on SublimeREPL

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, sublimerepl

I really like using sublime text 2 to write Python codes, however any time I try to run a script which has an input, the sublime text console reports an error. So, I decided to try `SublimeREPL`, however I've been searching for hours and I didn't find out how to run Python code...
could you guys help me?

I want to run the code on `SublimeREPL` as we do with the sublime text console (`CTRL+b`).. what I actually want to know is whether or not there's a way to do the same with `SublimeREPL`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? What exactly are you having a problem with? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19732006/edit) your question and describe exactly what you want to do, what you've tried to do so far, and the specific error(s), if any, you are getting.

Comment: uhm, I suppose I wasn't clear enough..
I wan to run the code on repl as we do with the sublime text console (crtl+b)..
what I actually want to know is whether there's a way to do the same with repl or not, 'cause I couldn't find any answer yet

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First "`Install Package Control`" from https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2

**Optional**(*To check the above package is successfully installed:
Click the `Preferences > Browse Packages`… at this folder
Click `Back Button` one time and then into the Installed Packages/ folder, check there will be `Package Control.sublime-package` file*)

then go to `Preferences > Package Control > Package Control: Install Package`  in sublime text 2

find `SublimeREPL` in list.

Restart SublimeText2

open `Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > Settings - Default` file copy all text from there.

then open `Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > Settings - User` and paste the text here.

Restart SublimeText2

Go to `Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python`

And you are done

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm all set up already.
The point is that I didn't find a way to run the code I wrote on repl, like we do normally with the sublime text console (ctrl+b)..

Comment: Yes, simply write and save your code on Sublime text2 editor. And after save go to `Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python-RUN Current file`

Comment: thanks for your answer! it was very helpfull!
btw, there's a shortcut for that command?

Comment: @user205820 yes, there is a shortcut, and there are several ways to run/transfer code in the REPL. First, open the REPL you want to use to evaluate your code, switch back to the tab with your code, and hit `Ctrl+,`, `f` to transfer the file to the REPL. Other commands are available by going to `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL` and `Transfer to REPL`.

Comment: Is this the same when I'm coding in Ruby or something like that ?

Comment: Whats the solution for Sublime Text 3 ? does sublimeREPL works for ST3 too ? or if not whats the solution.

Answer (score 78):

As [described here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2964&start=60#p25231), create a new Build System file and save it as `..\Packages\User\SublimeREPL-python.sublime-build`. The file should contain:

```
{
    "target": "run_existing_window_command", 
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}
```

Then go to your Python file tab and select Tools > Build System > SublimeREPL-python. Now, `Ctrl` + `B` should execute the current Python file, with the output in a new tab. If you use a two column layout, the REPL output should open in the second column. (This was using Sublime Text 3.)

Comment: This is absolutely perfect and worked first time. I don't understand why SublimeREPL doesn't do this out of the box. Thank you.

Comment: @sblair This is great. Two questions: (1) Is there a way to make it so that if a REPL tab is already open, it will simply reload in that tab (instead of opening a new one)? (2) Is there a way to use `Ctrl + B` and then leave REPL open so that it remains in interactive Python console?

Comment: @alexpmil Sorry, I don't know. But now that you mention it, both of those would be useful! Probably best to ask on the forum, but please leave an answer here if you find out how - I would upvote it!

Comment: @sblair, thanks, I use this to prevent the REPL from closing when `sys.exit()` is called.

Comment: This is the answer that should be accepted, works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexP.Miller For 2): you can get an interactive Python console by editing the entry for `repl_python_run` in  `Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`. Including the flag `-i` in the `cmd`. Got this from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM2LbXCkLDI

Answer (score 26):

### Steps to make Sublime Python Console which is Interactive and Reusable :

#### 1) Install SublimeREPL plugin :

> In Top Bar > "Tools" > "Command Palette" > "Package Control: Install Package"
>           Search for : "SublimeREPL" and install

---

#### 2) Create Build System :

> In Top Bar > "Tools" > "Build System" > "New Build System"

Replace all contents of the file with :

```
{
    "target": "run_existing_window_command", 
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}
```

Save the file as "PythonRepl.sublime-build" in the default "user" folder.

---

#### 3) Settings to make Console interactive and Reusable:

> |=>    Goto "Preferences" > "Browse Packages"
>
> |=>    Goto Folder : SublimeRepl
>
> |=>    Edit : sublimerepl.py

```
Replace : if view.id() == view_id

With    : if view.name() == view_id:
```

---

> |=>    Goto Folder : SublimeRepl/config/Python
>
> |=>    Edit : Main.sublime-menu

```
|=> Under "caption": "Python - RUN current file"

|=> Append : "-i", in "cmd" as : 

        "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file_basename"],

        "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "$file_basename"],

|=> Add : Before "external_id": "python"

        "view_id": "*REPL* [python]",

|=> Full Code as shown below :
    --------------------------------------------------
    {"command": "repl_open",
     "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
     "id": "repl_python_run",
     "mnemonic": "R",
     "args": {
        "type": "subprocess",
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "$file_basename"],
        "cwd": "$file_path",
        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
        "view_id": "*REPL* [python]",
        "external_id": "python",
        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
        }
    },
```

---

#### 4) Using  :

> 4.1) Open the Python file that you want to run in Sublime Text.
>
> 4.2) In Top Bar > "Tools" > "Build System" > "PythonRepl".
>
> 4.3) Build the Python file, by choosing In Top Bar > "Tools" > "Build"
>       or 
>       Using either the build shortcut (Ctrl+B for Windows, or ⌘ Command+B for Mac)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Tried many other answers but none didn't work. Thanks for this, works like a charm

Comment: you can also move interactive tab with the output to the second column and stop switching back and forth between two tabs :).

Comment: Perfect answer, Worked like a charm for me. +10

Comment: @VictorDi how to move the output to the 2nd column. can you please add your answer?

Comment: @akjprajapati View > Layout > Columns:2, then drag your Repl console to the second column.

Comment: Very nice -  it really helps to have a step-by-step guide, as the Sublime Text package config can feel a bit intimidating

Comment: Awesome! - nice job

Answer (score 19):

I want to expand on @sblair's response. @alexpmil asked in a comment how to prevent the REPL from closing.

1. In Sublime, go to Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages
2. In your packages, open `SublimeREPL\config\Python\Main.sublime-menu`.
3. Find the part that contains `id`: `repl_python_run`.
4. Under `args/cmd`, add `-i`. That's it.

For reference, mine looks like the following:

```
{"command": "repl_open",
 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
 "id": "repl_python_run",
 "mnemonic": "d",
 "args": {
     "type": "subprocess",
     "encoding": "utf8",
     "cmd": ["C:/Python34/python", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename"],
     "cwd": "$file_path",
     "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
     "external_id": "python",
     "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you know a way to re-use an already openned REPL tab ? The `-i` argument do prevents the REPL from closing, but when I re-build the same script, it will run in a new REPL tab.

Comment: I have the same issue as Seeven Byakko

Comment: @Seeven  To resue the same tab, add the following line in the "repl_python_run" command in SublimeREPL\config\Python\Main.sublime-menu, right before the "external_id": "python" argument:

view_id": "*REPL* [python]"