# Sublime Text 3 REPL - Open program in same REPL window

Tags: python, sublimetext3, read-eval-print-loop

I'll get to the point. I've installed SublimeREPL via Package Control, and I've pretty much set it up as I want it.

The only thing that's bothering me, is that every time I build a python script (CTRL+B), a new REPL window opens, even though I already have one open.

Is there a way to configure REPL to open new builds in an already open REPL window?

[image: Here's an example]

Answer (score 4):

SublimeREPL don't yet allow this, this could be a limitation in Sublime Text. You can ask developper for a implementation by opening a [ticket](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues) on his Github.

This question is a duplicate, but, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100899/re-use-tab-when-running-python-code-with-sublimerepl) is un-closable as when I want to flag it I have this output:

```
This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer
```

And we can't close this one as there is a bounty opened.

So thank you @MartjinPieters to check the facts before closing answer.