# Using SuplimeREPL to run R

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'm using Sublime text 3, and I'm trying to get SublimeREPL to print R files output in the interactive mode that is already open, without reopen a new interactive session every time I modify the .r file and hit cmd + B

I followed sblair procedure for Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732006/how-to-run-python-code-on-sublimerepl/23722631#23722631) and created R.sublime-build file with the following parameters:

```
{
"target": "run_existing_window_command", 
"id": "repl_r",
"file": "config/R/Main.sublime-menu"
```

}

and modified a default line in Main.sublime-menu:

```
"osx": ["R", "--interactive", "--no-readline"]
```

into:

```
"osx": ["R", "--slave", "-f", "$file"]
```

Now every time I hit cmd + B, I get a new window, with the output by itself!

I couldn't figure out how to make the same window that runs the interactive session to print the output stay running

Note: I know that I can just switch to the prompt window and type >source("FILE")
every time I change something, but I want to know if there's a way as easy as making changes to .r file, hit *some shortcut*, voalla your output is in the same prompt window you were working on.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly..

Yep, there is, just bind `"command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "file"}` to a key and when you hit that key it will pass your current file to the REPL prompt for that file.

What i do, that is even better, i got:

```
{ "keys": ["super+r"], "command": "build" },
{ "keys": ["super+b"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "file"} },
```

So i can build in the Sublime console with Cmd-R and in the REPL with Cmd-B.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I made that keybinding, and I'm getting a promote saying "Cannot find REPL for 'r'"

Comment: I'm afraid this feature is not even implemented as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33038545/834359) suggests ..

Comment: You have that warning, because you have to open a REPL prompt, while you have your open file in Sublime on focus; select the panel where your file is open and then open a REPL console, that's what i meant when i said "to the REPL prompt for THAT file".