# Python interactive mode on SublimeREPL

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I'm trying to run Python on SublimeREPL, but python is not on interactive mode.

So when I send a line to sublimeREPL, it just shows something if it's an error or if I print something.
How can I change python to interactive mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

After setting up Python on SublimeREPL, go to Keybindings - User and add this code below. It will be just like the normal PythonIDE!

```
[
{ "keys": ["f8"], "command": "repl_open", 
             "caption": "Python",
             "mnemonic": "p",
             "args": {
                "type": "subprocess",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
                "cwd": "$file_path",
                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                "external_id": "python"
                } }
]
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what i needed. It's important to note that this does have to go in Keybindings-user and not Main.sublime-menu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not understanding your problem with that? Python will only log data to the console if you print something or it encounters an error, there is nothing else to show usually.

Regardless, Python should be preconfigured on SublimeREPL. Look at [the documentation](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and if that doesn't help then look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732006/how-to-run-python-code-on-sublimerepl). However it doesn't sound like there's anything going wrong.