# Permission error 13 in Windows 10 for Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, windows-10, sublimetext3

I recently installed `SublimeREPL` from `PackageControl` and changed the path to `python IDE` to its location in `Main.sublime-menu` file and also created a new build file as shown in this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23722631/7773783]. But when I create a `.py` file and run it like this: `Tools --> SublimeREPL --> Python --> Python-RUN current file`, I am getting the following error:

[image]

How can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

An `Access Denied` error of `5` on Windows is an indication that you tried to execute a folder, which is not allowed.

Based on your description of how you set this up, my guess would be that when you set up the path to Python, you set it to the location that the Python interpreter is installed inside of. However, that particular setting is specifying the **what** to execute, not the **where** of what's going to get executed (although it can also contain *where* information as well).

If this is the case, then modifying that value to be the full path up to and including the Python interpreter should fix the problem; the value would be something like `C:\SomePath\Python36\bin\python.exe` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

just add the correct path
for instance:

> **C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe**

Helpful thread: https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/529

Answer (score 0):

The `Access is denied` is a permission error. Make sure to include the .exe file in the path e.g. `C:/Program Files (x86)/Python38/python.exe`