# The input() function is not working for me (Python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2. When building this code:

```
first = input()
print (first)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\21314", line 1, in <module>
    first = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Why?

Comment: Try executing the script from command line

Comment: A lot of IDEs don't take `input`. I think that maybe yours is one of them.

Comment: @AlexThornton Sublime Text is not an IDE, it's a very advanced text editor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the script from the terminal or command line.

Sublime Text 2 itself doesn't allow you to `input` anything during the build, so the `EOFError` is raised because your input is empty.

Possible **workaround** is described here: [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

The **complete solution** is to install SublimeREPL (a package for Sublime Text). Learn how to  from here: [Python input EOFError in Sublime Text 2](http://www.bestpythonide.com/python-input-eoferror-in-sublime-text-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution that still allows you to use Sublime's build systems, in case SublimeREPL doesn't exactly fit into your workflow. Create a new file with the following contents:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "c:/python33/python.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

and save it as `Packages/User/Python_cmd.sublime-build` where `Packages` is the folder opened when selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` - it should be `%APPDATA%/Sublime Text 2/Packages` for you.

Next, go to `Tools -> Build System` and select `Python_cmd` down at the bottom, then switch to your `.py` file and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build. A new command line window will open, allowing you to input values to your heart's content. When the program is done, the window will remain open, allowing you to examine output, tracebacks, etc. Just close the window to return to Sublime.

I highly recommend SublimeREPL for interactive development, and running small bits of code, but there are definitely times when you want to interact with your program in a command-line environment. This build system allows you to do that, without switching over to an open command window and manually running `python myprogram.py` every time you want to build.