# Can't input value in SublimeText on MAC

Tags: c, sublimetext2, clang

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int num;
  printf("Enter the Number :");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  printf("\nNumber = %d",num);
  return 0;
}
```

and when run this code I cant input the number , eventhough I didn't enter any number I get the output

```
Enter the Number :
Number = 1757380702[Finished in 0.1s]
```

What should I do for enter the input?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you said " I didn't enter any number I get the output" . If you do not give any number then how program can come out from scanf and and go ahead and exit?

Comment: @Mr.32 that may be the initializtion of num by compiler..I didn't enter anything just show the console output

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Sublime Text just doesn't support that--see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input). The only Mac text editor that I know for sure *will* do what you want is [Chocolat](https://chocolatapp.com/).

Comment: Wow, fussed with Sublime Text 3 for days, then installed Chocolat. Uninstalling Sublime Text 3.