# Sublime text 3 showing unnecessary output

Tags: sublimetext3

When I press `ctrl + B` in sublime text, it gives unnecessary output like path, dir etc. How to stop this behavior.

**Expected:**

```
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Getting:

```
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u .....
[dir:....
[path:....
```

Just included a excerpt of above, it shows the whole path and looks very cluttered. Moreover, sometimes it shows these other dir path etc, sometimes it doesn't. Also I am not using any packages, just the default v3 and the build system is python.

In addition, this only happens if there's is an error. Otherwise, it behaves as expected like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in altering how build systems work, you can clone and modify `Packages/Default/exec.py`, which is the default program that runs builds. Since you're using ST3, you'll need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control, select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` from the Command Palette, then select `Default` and `exec.py`. Before you do anything, change the name of class `ExecCommand` (on line 129 or thereabouts) to something like `MyExecCommand`, then use `Save As...` to save the file as `Packages/User/my_exec.py` so you don't interfere with the default version.

The changes you want are actually fairly simple, you just need to comment out a portion of the code. I'm running Build 3095, and the lines are 207-215 (they *may* be different in other versions of ST3):

```py
if shell_cmd:
    self.debug_text += "[shell_cmd: " + shell_cmd + "]\n"
else:
    self.debug_text += "[cmd: " + str(cmd) + "]\n"
self.debug_text += "[dir: " + str(os.getcwd()) + "]\n"
if "PATH" in merged_env:
    self.debug_text += "[path: " + str(merged_env["PATH"]) + "]"
else:
    self.debug_text += "[path: " + str(os.environ["PATH"]) + "]"
```

Once you've done that, save the file. Now, open your build system and add:

```js
"target": "my_exec",
```

to the second line, just after the opening curly brace `{`. Verify that everything works as you wish, and that should be it.

Comment: thx, that worked. I changed the default exec.py bcoz I don't think would be needing that buggy irritating thing. It will be good for others if you can list out your answer in points and add the steps for dthe link for package installer. like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input