# input() command not working on Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, sublimetext3

I'm trying to write an `add()` function using `input()`, however it seem that the input doesn't really work for me.
The module is as following:

```
def add (n1, n2):

    return (n1+n2)

def main ():

    print (add(input("Enter number one, please:"),input ("Enter number two, please:")))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When ran, I just get the "Enter number one, please:" prompt, and when inputting an actual number and pressing ENTER, nothing really happens.
I tried getting the "Sublime Input" package, but to no avail.

I'd like to get this to run without resorting to Ubuntu (I'm using Windows 8.1).

Comment: I'm not familiar with sublime text and the way it takes input in its interactive mode, but you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python because that's not going to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Your code worked when I ran it on Windows 7, it might not be the best way to do that task, but it works.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input

Comment: Even if that worked, it might not do what you expect it to do. For 1 and 2 you will get '12' because `input` returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

First off `input` in Python 3 no longer interprets the data type you are giving to it. This in essence means that everything you give it will be read as a string. This mean the `add` function will not work as you are expecting it to. To fix this change the code to the following:

```
def add (n1, n2):

    return (n1+n2)

def main ():

    print (add(float(input("Enter number one, please:")),float(input ("Enter number two, please:"))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The addition of the builtin `float` function ensures that the input in converted into a float and you can therefore to math operations on it.

Secondly, Sublime Text 3 is still in its beta development stage. This means that some features might not work as you would expect. Try using Sublime Text 2. Also I ran the above code in the command line using `python add.py` and it works perfectly. NOTE: I saved the file as `add.py`

Comment: I did as you said, the module looks like this now:
def add (n1, n2):
 return (n1+n2)

def main ():
 print (add(float(input("Enter number one, please:")),float(input("Enter number two, please:"))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()

I also tried building a module using String since you said it's the default for input(), but it still didn't work.
This was it:

def main():
 person = input("Give me a word:")
 print (person)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()