# python3 input using sublime text 3

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am trying to use the input feature on python for my program. I installed **SublimeREPL** but I still cant seem to figure out how to provide an input for my program. (coming from a complete beginner)

[image]

Comment: You have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input

Comment: Yes but I don't know where to type my input in

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **exact** details of what you did to get the output shown in your image.

Comment: did you try in the part of the window that asks `Tell me something:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `input` from within an editor can be tricky. A simple solution would be to run your program from the command line. Open a terminal and change into the directory where your script `user_inputs_intro.py` is located and type:

```
python user_inputs_intro.py
```

Now, you will see the `Tell me something:` and should be able to type something that will be echoed back after you press enter.