# Sublime Text build system for input/output in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, sublimetext3

I want to use Sublime Text in Ubuntu for python programming and want to write a build system that takes input from a mentioned file and prints output to other mentioned file. I have done same for c++ using this code :

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++ -std=c++11 ${file} -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} && ${file_path}/${file_base_name}<${file_path}/inputf.in>${file_path}/outputf.in"],
    "shell" : true
}
```

Comment: You should post your answer... as an answer. I did it for you.

Comment: Thanks @J.Chomel  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Answer (score 0):

Tushar found the solution for himself by modifying the above code like below:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python ${file}<${file_path}/inputf.in>${file_path}/outputf.in"],
    "shell":true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if somebody is seeking a solution to the same problem in **Windows**. A few changes to the answer suggested by J.Chomel. will do the work.
But first, **Save your input and output files in the same folder** you are working.

```
{
"cmd": ["python", "${file}","<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
}
```

This is by far **the fastest way to run a python file** taking the input from a file and saving the output in a file for me. Seriously. :)