# Confused by print function using Sublime Text 3 with Python build

Tags: python, printing, sublimetext3

I have configured Sublime text 3 to compile and execute Python 3.5 code and have successfully run several small programs. However when I try and run this simple code to calculate the square of a number the user can input, the console will not return the final answer:

```
def square():
  num = int(input("Please enter the number you wish to square: "))
  answer = num ** 2
  print (answer)

square()
```

In Sublime Text 3 it will ask the user for input but then not print the answer. If I run it in IDLE though it will print the answer. As I said I can run other small programs involving print (like Hello World for example) so I am not sure what is wrong. All help appreciated I am just starting out so please forgive my lack of experience.

Comment: build in sublime is not interactive..

Comment: Any chance you could expand on that? Not really sure what that means. I can run codes and print to the console but just not in this case

Comment: sublime does not accept user input, even though you can type in the build box it will not accept the data and your code will not continue

Comment: just run it in your terminal

Comment: Ah right cool thanks. I'll just run anything that requires input from IDLE in future then. Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code through my terminal. It ran perfectly. I wrote the same code in Sublime Text 3 as I use the same editor. I don't think there is any input/output exception for sublime. You might want to restart the terminal and then try creating a new .py file to run this code.

[image: Please zoom the image to see your output.]