# I'm not getting any output after taking user input using input() in python.

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = input("enter something:")
print(s)
d = input("enter something else")
print(d)
```

so once I input a string.. the program does not proceed.. nor does it print the string. (i'm a noob at python rn)
[I'm using sublimeText3 + Anaconda]

[Check the screenshot out, it'd be more helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI9Xm.png)

Comment: This is an issue with your IDE. Run this code in the command prompt and it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Comment: Its not related to the question but I suggest you use python from shell It will help you to only focus python  not any other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on Python 2 or Python 3? Actually, with Python3, in terminal, your code runs fine to me. To check Python version, just type in terminal:

```
python --version
```

if it yields something like Python 2.7, try to run your code executing python3 instead. Otherwise, consider using `raw_input()` :)

EDIT: as others pointed out, it could something glitchy with your IDE. Try with terminal first!