# i need an external terminal like gnome for sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I use sublime text 3 in lubuntu in oracle virtual box for python coding. I want an external terminal to execute my scripts written in the text editor. I wrote the following code and built a new system,

```
{ 
  "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -u
  $file;echo;echo Press ENTER to exit; read line\"'"],
  "shell": true 
}
```

when I press `ctrl+build` it says no build system found. I have also installed gnome using the lxterminal. What should I do in the terminal to get the codes running?

Comment: What exactly does *"[I] have also installed gnome using the lxterminal"* mean? If you have replaced LXDE with Gnome you are not strictly speaking using Lubuntu any longer. Perhaps you are looking for a replacement for `gnome-terminal` which works on an LXDE system; but you obviously already know about `lxterminal`...?

Comment: `"shell": true`  looks suspicious here; but I am not familiar with Sublime so maybe it's weird.

Answer (score -1):

I can't correct your code, but if you won't be able to fix it, try SublimeREPL package. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605079/9188282) is a simple guide on how to do it.