# Sublime Text doesn't execute all lines of Python code

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Using unregistered version of Sublime Text (is that the issue)?

When I run the following code it prompts me for my first name, I enter it and click enter, then nothing happens:

```
dict_1 = []
count = 0

while count < 3:
    fn = input('What is your first name:')
    ln = input('What is your last name:')
    dict_1.append({
        "first_name": fn,
        "last_name": ln
        })
    count += 1

print(dict_1)
```

However when I run the exact same code in PyCharm it prompts for first and last name 3 times as per the loop, then prints out the resulting dictionary.

I prefer Sublime Text to Pycharm (less bloated) but if it doesn't execute all the code then it probably won't work for me.

Any ideas?  Is there some setting in Sublime Text I am missing?

Comment: Do u have python 3 in sublime or are you running on python 2

Comment: @BOi . Python 3, I think?  Otherwise it wouldn't have run at all I am guessing because of the print() with parentheses, also the input vs raw_input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Comment: If you're using python 2 to run it on sublime text it doesn't know what input is. So it wont ask you for one

Comment: @dfundako exactly

Comment: @BOi I found that link by Googling "Sublime text python input"

Comment: @JD2775 please read the link. It should solve your question. Next time make sure you google your questions before asking it here. We don't want to keep answering duplicates :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sublime Text "Build results" pannel (bottom of the interface):

[image]

is not interactive, you cannot type input there.

To solve this, I have added, in addition to the standard <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> build shortcut, another shortcut (in Menu *Preferences > Key Bindings - User*):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+b"], "command": "python_run" }
```

that allows to launch the current file with Python **in a new terminal window** (there, you can input some data).

Here is the `python_run.py` file (to be copied in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User`):

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess

class PythonRunCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        command = 'cmd /k "C:\Python27\python.exe" %s' % sublime.active_window().active_view().file_name()
        subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, Sublime's console does not support input. If you want to run programs which need input from standard input. You can run it in a GUI terminal. You can modify Sublime's builtin [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) for python and add a variant for Python.

1. In order to modify the builtin python build system. You need to install the package [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer). Follow the guide there to install it.
2. After installing PackageResourceViewer, bring up the package control panel by using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. Then input `prv`, and choose `Open Resource`.
   [image]
3. Then input `python`, and choose the first item in the result list.

[image]

4. In the pop-up panel, choose `Python.sublime-build`, [image].

In the opened file, use the following settings:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        },

        {
            "name": "Run in console",

            "windows":{
                "shell_cmd": "start cmd /k python -u \"$file\""
            },
            "linux":{
                "shell_cmd": "xterm -hold -e python -u \"$file\""
            },
             "osx":{
                "shell_cmd": "xterm -hold -e python -u \"$file\""
            }

        }
    ]
}
```