# Sublime Text 3 not accepting input()

Tags: python, sublimetext3

The code works as expected in the python shell, launched through idle. When running the file via sublime text, it only prints "please enter your price:" to the console without running the remainder of the code after submitting my input. Hitting enter on the console only creates a new line. When running the code in the python shell, the rest of the code executes after submitting the int into the tip calculator.

```
def calculateit():
     price = input("please enter your price: ")
     tip = int(price) * 0.25
     final = int(tip) + int(price)
     print ("since the price of your meal is " + str(price) + " your tip is " + str(tip))
     print ("the total cost of your meal is " + str(final))

calculateit()
```

Comment: Sublime doesn't take user input last time I checked

Comment: Please try searching for the problem before posting. https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/is-this-a-bug-python-input-not-working-in-build-or-console/25719

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute code in Sublime there is no way to capture input. More technically, the console is connected to `stderr` and `stdout` but not `stdin`. So it's not possible to run an interactive program from within Sublime directly.

However after seeing your code, a question arises - why don't you cast your `price` variable at the first time with user `input` method, so that you won't need multiple time to cast it from `str` to `int` and vice versa. To make you clear of this, see the following code , it's exactly the same but more smart approach i think.

```
def calculateit():
    price = int(input("please enter your price: "))
    tip = price * 0.25
    final = tip + price
    print (f"since the price of your meal is {price} your tip is {tip}" )
    print (f"the total cost of your meal is {final}" )

calculateit()
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will just need to run it in idle instead. The answer to your question is mostly just because I didn't know better. I was thinking of it line by line.

Comment: @RobertN please, mark the answer if its helpful to you. Thanks