# While loop is not working as expected

Tags: python, while-loop

After I build and run the code, "Enter word: " is output once and that's it. Stays blank after entering any word. What am I missing? Here's the code:

```
word = "cool"
guess = " "

while guess != word:
    guess = input("Enter word: ")

print("you win!")
```

Comment: The indentation is all correct. just got messed up while I posted the question here

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Also, how are you running the code?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/UnpleasantImpracticalFont  ... you need to be using python 3 (in order to use `input` ,,, otherwise you need `raw_input`)

Comment: This works for me in python3. For your input are you doing `cool` or `"cool"`? It works with the double quotes and does not work without them.

Comment: Its simple: `raw_input()` returns string values, while `input()` return integer values. You have to use `raw_input()`.

Comment: @FilipGrebowski Since "cool" does not have an integer value, the program would crash. Since it does not crash, the OP is _not_ using Python 2.7.

Comment: @DYZ I agree! Thanks!

Comment: I'm using python 3.7...using the sublime editor...raw_input() didn't work either

Comment: For me, your given code works in Python 3.4.5; in Python 2.7, it errors out saying that "name 'cool' is not defined".  In neither case do I get your "one-and-done" effect.

Comment: so this code works in 3.6.1...but not 3.7 , which i'm using

Comment: Please try your code the way we have to: copy it from your posting here, paste it into your editor, and run the result.  Do you still see the problem?

Comment: @Prune yes. Still the same problem...something to do with python 3.7?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Python 3.7, but you're probably trying to run your code in Sublime Text's console, which is not intended for this, see [this link on ST forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/running-python-on-sublime-console/18621).

Comment: This runs fine. There is no issue with your code above. You must be compiling it incorrectly.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille but I installed the sublimeREPL package as well..that should make it work right?

Comment: @MjM8082 yeah code seems to be ok.

Comment: Something strange with sublime editor. The code works fine in PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. You just can't input in the Sublime Text terminal from the standard download. That's why it's not doing anything after you type a word and hit enter. Check out this post for a python workout:

[Sublime Text Console Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)