# the program just keeps on taking input in sublime text terminal window

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

no output is generated
 
the sublime text terminal windows just keeps on taking input

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
    int anumber;
    cout<<"please enter a number of decimal type :";
    cin>>anumber;
    cout<<"was this your number :"<<anumber;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running the program on the command line? It should work as expected. You hit Enter after typing the number, right (just to be sure)?

Comment: yes after  hitting enter it does nothing the cursor just simply moves on a new line every time i hit enter in the sublime text window

Comment: the programs terminates after i enter the value when i run in the ubuntu terminal

Comment: Your issue is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input) even though you're not using Python or Sublime Text 2; Sublime does not allow you to interact with programs that are displaying their output in the output panel; you need to craft a build system that runs it externally instead.