# Sublime Text 3 - split windows at launch

Tags: sublimetext3

Running Windows and Sublime Text (3.1.1 Build 3176) for the last few days, every time I launch the editor it starts with one window split into two panes. This happens whether I

- launch from a command prompt with 'subl';
- launch form the window menu; or
- select a file from the file manager and edit it

It never remembers that I have set it back to a single pane with Alt-Shift 1. I cannot find a setting to change this behaviour.

Help pls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Comment: There's not a setting for this because the default is to open a single pane window. if you're seeing all new windows always being split in half, the most likely reason is that you have installed a plugin or package that's doing this.

Comment: Thank-you, that solved my problem. Cleaned out a couple of old packages related to columns which I didn't actively use; but must have accidentally tripped some keystrokes in one of them.