# Python3 Sublime Text3 Not showing the input value as output

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am using sublime text3 for Python on Ubuntu 18.04. But I can't print anything when I am taking input. Like I can print this

```
print("Hello")
```

but I can't print this

```
test= int(input())
print(test)
```

I give input but it doesn't show any output.
My python build code is

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

[image: But it doesn't work]

[image: It works]

I have followed this [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input) 
But not working. Here is the screenshot using SublimeRELP package
[image: using sublimeREPL]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Comment: What does not work? Your edit is not enough to avoid marked as duplicate unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, I use sublimeREPL [as like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input). But again this problem occurs. Accidently I found that I was pressing my num Enter but it worked with my general Enter button. After pressing the general Enter button, it works fine.