# Java user console input on sublime text 3 not working

Tags: java, input, console, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to get the user to enter their name and have it be printed out on java using Sublime Text 3. After the user enters their name when a message prompts them for it, their name is supposed to be printed out but it justs skips over to a new blank line. It works on online compilers but not on Sublime. How do I get user console input to work on Java Sublime Text 3?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SocSecProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        input.close();
        System.out.println(name);

    }

}
```

Comment: Google: `How to run Java Code from Sublime Text 3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input)

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch execution in a separate console, not the sublime text pseudo console.
The solution is to launch with START command in a batch file .bat
for example:

```
START CMD /K %RELATIVE_PATH%\jdk\bin\java -cp %~dp1 %~n1
```

where %1 is the file class with main method. Go to the batch syntax documentation if necessary... Your build system in sublime must launch a batch file with this kind of
instruction.