# How do I use the input function in Python, using Sublime Text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning about user input and while loops. Here is an example:

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
print(f"\nHello, {name}!")
```

As a result the only output I get is:

---

### Please enter your name:

Whereas the book I am reading has a different output:

---

### Please enter your name: Eric
Hello, Eric!

How do I get the second output?

Comment: Did you try to type something after you've seen the prompt?

Comment: They do not support it. [See  this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605079/8153505)

Comment: I tried typing in the output window "Alex" and then pressed enter. Nothing happened...

Comment: Python programming is not what the Sublime Text console is good for. Install python 3 and run the `python` command, or set up ipython, or use an online python interpreter.

Comment: @Nam Nguyen I use Sublime Text 3, but will follow your link anyway to see if I solve this problem

Comment: @Jerry101 I have Python 3.8  Do you mean to run the code in the command prompt - python?

Comment: Subl 3 still not support it @alexcm113

Comment: Yes, @alexcm113, run the `python` command, which opens an interactive python shell, then type the `name =...` and `print...` commands into it. If `python` runs Python 2.7 on your computer, try the `python3` command or else install [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and use that to install a Python 3 virtual environment.