# input() function not working in Sublime text

Tags: python, input, sublimetext3, prompt

I have the following function:

```
years=2
double_rate=(years*12)//3
number_of_rabbits=11
answer=number_of_rabbits*double_rate
print(answer)
```

I want to generalize the code by being able to input years and number_of_rabbits variables

```
years=input("select number of years: ")
print(years)
double_rate=(years*12)//3
number_of_rabbits=input("select number of rabbits: ")
print(number_of_rabbits)
answer=number_of_rabbits*double_rate
print(answer)
```

However the editor (sublime text) only prompts me for the first input variable. I am not able set the second one, "select number of rabbits", nor does it print the new answer

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Sublime text always had [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input) with `input`.

Comment: Not sure about Sublime, but you have to convert the input to `int` before you can calculate with it, e.g. `years = int(input(...))`

Comment: Also, not sure what you are computing here, but I think it should be `answer = number_of_rabbits * 2**double_rate`

Comment: 'number_of_rabbits' doubes every 3 months. So if I use the first inputs I will have 88 as the result

Answer (score 0):

The number of years you enter is saved as a string, not an int (or float). So when you try to calculate double_rate, you're multiplying a string by 12 (which is fine) and then floor dividing the result by 3, which doesn't work.

Try `years = int(input("Select number of years: "))` instead.

Comment: thanks, am entering, say, 4 in the output section of the editor, it still doesn't prompt the second input. Is there something wrong with the double_rate line?